# Редактирование UILabel

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Добрый день. В моем проекте есть UILabel и три кнопки, с помощью которых редактируется содержимое label:

```
- (IBAction)setToOneButton:(id)sender
{  
    [_label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1"]];  
}

- (IBAction)setToTwoButton:(id)sender
{  
    [_label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"2"]];  
}

- (IBAction)setToThreeButton:(id)sender
{  
    [_label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"3"]];  
}
```

Но в таком случае редактируется все содержимое label, то есть старое значение удаляется а новое появляется. Хотелось бы, чтобы при нажатии кнопки старый текст в лейбле не удалялся а к нему дописывалась еще одна цифра. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать.
Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все просто :)

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@1",_label.text]
```

И так со всеми действиями.

Для удаления предудущего символа можно добавить следующию функцию:

```
- (IBAction)removePrevChar:(id)sender
{  
    if (_label.text.length > 0) {
         //будет выполнено если длина _label.text больше чем 0, иначе ничего не надо удалять
         _label.text = [_label.text substringToIndex:_label.text.length - 1];
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. А не подскажете еще, как удалить предыдущую цифру?

Comment: @Ruslan_T Ем... Предыдущию от чего?... Удаление предыдущей цифры то же самое, что и замена (как у вас в примере).

Comment: Я имею ввиду вот что: к примеру Вам надо набрать 123123, но Вы случайно набрали 123122, и теперь нужно нажать на кнопку "Удалить символ" чтобы стереть 2 и потом написать 3.

Comment: @Ruslan_T вот так?

Comment: Да, спасибо огромное!